# Можно ли задать цвет заднего фона для QLabel без использование css

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, qcheckbox, qpropertyanimation

Можно ли задать цвет заднего фона для `QLabel` без использование `сss`

```
class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__( *args, **kwargs)

    def _set_color(self, col):
        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background, QtGui.QColor(col))
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setPalette(palette)


    color = QtCore.pyqtProperty(QtGui.QColor, fset=_set_color)


class Test:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.width = 48
        self.height = 24
        self.border_radius = self.height // 2
        self.switch_radius = self.height - 4
        self.switch_border_radius = self.switch_radius // 2

        self.switch_color = '#ffffff'
        self.active_background_color = '#240DC4'
        self.disable_background_color = '#CCCCCC'

        self.animation_duration = 400

        self.background = self._make_background() 

        # Для примера вызываем метод смены заднего фона с конструктора класса
        self._change_background()


    def _make_background(self):
        background = MyLabel(self.parent)
        background.setObjectName("label_5")
        background.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        background.setStyleSheet(
            "border-radius: %ipx;" \
            "background-color: %s;"  % (self.border_radius, self.disable_background_color)
        )

        return background


    def _change_background(self):
        self.background_color_animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.background, b"color")
        self.background_color_animation.setDuration(self.animation_duration)
        self.background_color_animation.setStartValue(QtGui.QColor(50, 50, 50))
        self.background_color_animation.setEndValue(QtGui.QColor(255, 50, 50))
        self.background_color_animation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InOutCubic)
        self.background_color_animation.start()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749798/qlabel-set-color-of-text-and-background

Comment: Проблема в том, что таким образом слетает border-radius

Comment: Опубликуйте пример вашего кода, который демонстрирует что у вас там слетает и лучше расскажите/покажите, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: добавил пример и фото того что выходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не могу воспроизвести ваш пример, потому что он не воспроизводимый. Но глядя на ваше изображение, я вам покажу что-то похожее на то, что вы излбразили.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QSize, QPoint, QPointF, QRectF, pyqtProperty,
    QEasingCurve, QPropertyAnimation, QSequentialAnimationGroup, pyqtSlot)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QBrush, QPaintEvent, QPen, QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel,
    QCheckBox, QApplication)


class AnimatedToggle(QCheckBox):
    _transparent_pen = QPen(Qt.transparent)
    _light_grey_pen = QPen(Qt.lightGray)

    def __init__(
            self,
            parent=None,
            bar_color=Qt.gray,
            checked_color="#00B0FF",
            handle_color=Qt.white,
            pulse_unchecked_color="#44999999",
            pulse_checked_color="#4400B0EE"
        ):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._bar_brush = QBrush(bar_color)
        self._bar_checked_brush = QBrush(QColor(checked_color).lighter())
        self._handle_brush = QBrush(handle_color)
        self._handle_checked_brush = QBrush(QColor(checked_color))
        self._pulse_unchecked_animation = QBrush(QColor(pulse_unchecked_color))
        self._pulse_checked_animation = QBrush(QColor(pulse_checked_color))

        self.setContentsMargins(8, 0, 8, 0)
        self._handle_position = 0
        self._pulse_radius = 0

        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"handle_position", self)
        self.animation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.InOutCubic)
        self.animation.setDuration(200)                                         
        
        self.pulse_anim = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"pulse_radius", self)
        self.pulse_anim.setDuration(350)                                    
        self.pulse_anim.setStartValue(10)
        self.pulse_anim.setEndValue(20)

        self.animations_group = QSequentialAnimationGroup()
        self.animations_group.addAnimation(self.animation)
        self.animations_group.addAnimation(self.pulse_anim)

        self.stateChanged.connect(self.setup_animation)                      

    def sizeHint(self):            
        return QSize(58, 45)

    def hitButton(self, pos: QPoint):           
        return self.contentsRect().contains(pos)

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def setup_animation(self, value):
        self.animations_group.stop()
        if value:
            self.animation.setEndValue(1)
        else:
            self.animation.setEndValue(0)
        self.animations_group.start()

    def paintEvent(self, e: QPaintEvent):
        contRect = self.contentsRect()
        handleRadius = round(0.24 * contRect.height())

        p = QPainter(self)
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)                 

        p.setPen(self._transparent_pen)
        barRect = QRectF(
            0, 0,
            contRect.width() - handleRadius, 0.40 * contRect.height()
        )
        barRect.moveCenter(contRect.center())
        rounding = barRect.height() / 2
        trailLength = contRect.width() - 2 * handleRadius
        xPos = contRect.x() + handleRadius + trailLength * self._handle_position

        if self.pulse_anim.state() == QPropertyAnimation.Running:
            p.setBrush(
                self._pulse_checked_animation if
                self.isChecked() else self._pulse_unchecked_animation)
            p.drawEllipse(QPointF(xPos, barRect.center().y()),
                          self._pulse_radius, self._pulse_radius)

        if self.isChecked():
            p.setBrush(self._bar_checked_brush)
            p.drawRoundedRect(barRect, rounding, rounding)
            p.setBrush(self._handle_checked_brush)

        else:
            p.setBrush(self._bar_brush)
            p.drawRoundedRect(barRect, rounding, rounding)
            p.setPen(self._light_grey_pen)
            p.setBrush(self._handle_brush)

        p.drawEllipse(
            QPointF(xPos, barRect.center().y()),
            handleRadius, handleRadius)

        p.end()

    @pyqtProperty(float)
    def handle_position(self):
        return self._handle_position

    @handle_position.setter
    def handle_position(self, pos):
        self._handle_position = pos
        self.update()

    @pyqtProperty(float)
    def pulse_radius(self):
        return self._pulse_radius

    @pulse_radius.setter
    def pulse_radius(self, pos):
        self._pulse_radius = pos
        self.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QWidget()

    mainToggle = AnimatedToggle()
    secondaryToggle = AnimatedToggle(
            checked_color="#FFB000",
            pulse_checked_color="#44FFB000"
    )
    mainToggle.setFixedSize(mainToggle.sizeHint())       
    secondaryToggle.setFixedSize(mainToggle.sizeHint())  

    window.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
    window.layout().addWidget(QLabel("Main Toggle"))
    window.layout().addWidget(mainToggle)
    window.layout().addWidget(QLabel("Secondary Toggle"))
    window.layout().addWidget(secondaryToggle)

    mainToggle.stateChanged.connect(secondaryToggle.setChecked)

    window.resize(100, 200)                                        
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]